# Reading a file from salesforce aura helper recursion problem

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, promises, html-area-component, aura-method

I'm trying to read a file in an async way on aura helper, but recursion is not happening, is just executed once. The code is pretty simple and tried a lot of approaches but no one work.

I try with the return keyword on the onload function, also with the keyword self but looks like aura does not find the function `this.uploadPromise` to be invoked again.

Controller

```js
handleFilesChange:function (component, event, helper) {
    var fileSize = component.get("v.FileList")[0].size;
    var file = component.get("v.FileList")[0];

    helper.uploadPromise(0, fileSize, file).then(function (result) {
        console.log('done!!!'+result);
    },function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $A.reportError("error message here", error);
    });
}
```

Helper

```js
 uploadPromise: function (startposi, endposi, file) {
    console.log('coming into  recursive function : startposition:' + startposi + ',endpposition' + file.size + '.file:' + file);
    var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 320 * 1024;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (startposi < endposi) {
            console.log('Reading from:' + startposi + ',until;' + (startposi + BYTES_PER_CHUNK ) + '/' + endposi);
            var chunk = file.slice(startposi, BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
            reader.onload = function (e) { // return handler function for 'onload' event
                startposi+= e.target.result.byteLength;
                console.log('before recursion: startposition:' + startposi + ',endpposition' + file.size + '.file:' + file + ",chunk size:" + e.target.result.byteLength);
                this.uploadPromise(startposi, file.size, file);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('finished reading file'); // it shows the content of the file
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve("finish");
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Component

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<aura:component description="FileUploadPromises" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="uploadUrl" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="FileList" type="Object"/>
    <ui:inputText label="Enter URL" class="field" value="{!v.uploadUrl}"/>
    <lightning:input aura:id="file-input" type="file" files="{!v.FileList}" label="Files promises"
                     name="file" multiple="false" onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }"/>
</aura:component>
```

I expected the recursion to be executed as a normal recursion call but just is invoked once. I already tested this approach with a pure javascript approach and works fine, the issue is when is migrated to aura in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call helper from the helper. The trick to do this is to pass the helper instance from the Controller:

Controller:

```
handleFilesChange:function (component, event, helper) {
    var fileSize = component.get("v.FileList")[0].size;
    var file = component.get("v.FileList")[0];

    helper.uploadPromise(0, fileSize, file, helper).then(function (result) {
        console.log('done!!!'+result);
    },function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $A.reportError("error message here", error);
    });
}
```

Helper:

```
uploadPromise: function (startposi, endposi, file , helper) {
    console.log('coming into  recursive function : startposition:' + startposi + ',endpposition' + file.size + '.file:' + file);
    var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 320 * 1024;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (startposi < endposi) {
            console.log('Reading from:' + startposi + ',until;' + (startposi + BYTES_PER_CHUNK ) + '/' + endposi);
            var chunk = file.slice(startposi, BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
            reader.onload = function (e) { // return handler function for 'onload' event
                startposi+= e.target.result.byteLength;
                console.log('before recursion: startposition:' + startposi + ',endpposition' + file.size + '.file:' + file + ",chunk size:" + e.target.result.byteLength);
                helper.uploadPromise(startposi, file.size, file,helper);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('finished reading file'); // it shows the content of the file
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve("finish");
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Pranay, just tried the approach you suggest but only get executed twice.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to send helper from 'uploadPromise'. Updated code with fix.

Comment: Thanks Pranay, now the recursion works pretty well. Now i have an issue reading the file because its triggering the recursion before reading the file so the recursion goes to an endless loop. Do you have any suggestion?